# Want title in simple numeric not italic through bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I am working on book and in that book I \cite{title} many times and it is printed in italic form, not in simple form. I changed various styles to print in simple numeric form. But did not get results. How I can make it simple?. Here is code

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@book{is4562000,
title={Indian Standard Plain and reinforced concrete--code of
     practice (IS 456 : 2000)},
shorttitle = {IS 456~:~2000},
author={{Cement and Concrete Sectional Committee, CED 2}},
journal={New Delhi: },
year={2000},
publisher={Bureau of Indian Standards}, 
}

@book{is555,
 title = {IS 555~:~1980}
 }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
 style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
This is bibliography using biblatex \cite{is4562000}.
  \citetitle{is4562000}.    
  \citeyear{is4562000}.
  \citeauthor{is4562000}.
  \citetitle{is555}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:[image]
How I can print numeric title  without italic?

Answer (score 10):

You just need to change the format. Insert these lines into your preamble or, better yet, into biblatex.cfg (just create such a file in your working directory if it doesn't exist yet):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\textbf{#1}}
```

The first line will change the title in the bibliography, the second in citations. You will notice that the titles are now not in italics, but in bold text -- that's what `\textbf{#1}` did.

Now, you don't really want the bold text. Therefore, you change these lines:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{#1}
```

All titles will be printed in normal style: neither in italics nor bold.

Suppose you decide that you do want booktitles printed normally, while all other titles (articles, reports etc.) are printed in italics. You can do it by passing an optional argument to the command:

```
% Format for bibliography
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{{#1}}

% Format for citations
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{citetitle}{{#1}}
```

The optional argument contains the types (book, article etc.) the format should be applied to. You can also use a list of types (e.g. `\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book]{title}{#1}`).

The starred version of the command clears all existing formatting before applying the formatting directive. I changed one of your entry types to "article", and without the star, the default format was used. So it may be a good idea to use the starred version for the general format of a field and the normal version if you pass an optional argument to the command.

Here is a MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@book{is4562000,
title={{Indian Standard Plain and reinforced concrete--code of
     practice (IS 456 : 2000)}},
shorttitle = {IS 456~:~2000},
author={{Cement and Concrete Sectional Committee, CED 2}},
year={2000},
publisher={Bureau of Indian Standards}, 
}

@article{is555,
 title = {{IS 555~:~1980}},
 author={{Cement and Concrete Sectional Committee, CED 2}},
 journal={{New Delhi}},
 year={2000}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\textbf{#1}}            % Format for bibliography
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\textbf{#1}}        % Format for citations

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\section{Bold titles}
Book title:  \citetitle{is4562000}.    

Article title:  \citetitle{is555}

\printbibliography

\section{Plain titles}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}                      % Format for bibliography
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{#1}                  % Format for citations

Book title:  \citetitle{is4562000}.    

Article title:  \citetitle{is555}

\printbibliography

\section{Different titles}
% Format for bibliography
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1}

% Format for citations
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{citetitle}{#1} 

Book title:  \citetitle{is4562000}.    

Article title:  \citetitle{is555}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

(I reused your bibliography file, but modified it a bit. By the way, I couldn't get your code to compile; apparently the bibliography style uses language settings, so I had to load babel.)

Comment: Why is placing the commands in a `.cfg` better than in the preamble?

Comment: @samcarter Because it keeps the preamble clean and smaller. That might not be an issue for a MWE, but if you have a big document -- remember, the original poster is working on a book -- you might have several packages with lots of options (biblatex, glossaries, the KOMA-classes). I think, in such a case it is better to use individual config-files. Then you instantly know which option belongs to which package. Also, you don't need a `.cfg` for just two lines of formatting directives -- but what if you set up your own citation commands etc., I wouldn't want _that_ to clutter up my preamble! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I just wondered if there is a technical reason, but keeping things clean one way or another  makes perfect sense.

Comment: The downside to it is, you might get lost between editor tabs. :-D

Comment: Thank you, Andreas for giving me detail answer. It solve my problems :-). But is there any style which provide such functionality automatically?.

Comment: @ManpreetDhiman Such cosmetic changes are rather trivial to implement, so they are the last thing I would look for when choosing a style. Do you have any other requirements? I don't know about civic engineering, but I work on a psychologist's thesis right now, and their citation rules (APA style) are so complex that you could study them for years and still get the citations wrong. :-) If I had opted for a style just because it prints the authors and titles the way I want but still gets the citations wrong, it would be a nightmare! I would choose a style that gets most things right and change…

Comment: @ManpreetDhiman … the details later on. Perhaps you could tell us what exactly you need, or what subject you are writing about. In the best case, a style that fits all your needs regarding bibliography and citations already exists. Otherwise, I or somebody else might know a style that comes close to it -- you would have to fine-tune certain things again, though. Anyway, it can be easily done with biblatex. (Take "easily" with a grain of salt, but it is really as easy as pie compared to changing bibtex styles! :-D)

Comment: Actually I am working on  book and it is related with Civil Engineering. I have following requirements.

Comment: 1) Want to print title in normal form. 2) somewhere I want to print shortitle and somewhere I want longtitle, So what I should do?. 3) And book contain long author name that you already see (author={{Cement and Concrete Sectional Committee, CED 2}}). I do not want to print it as it is long. So, what is appropriate for it. 4) Why @STANDARD is used?. What is its main feature? Is IS code (IS 456:2000) should be in @STANDARD?.

Comment: Kindly suggest me something for my questions.

Comment: @ManpreetDhiman Regarding 2): Say you have two articles (A and B). Do you always want to  print the longtitle of A and the shorttitle of B, or do you want to print sometimes the longtitle and sometimes the shorttitle of A? In the first case, just set the shorttitle field of B (but not of A); `\citetitle{B}` should then use the shorttitle. If you want to mix both versions for one entry, use `\citefield{A}{title}` or `\citefield{A}{shorttitle}`.

Comment: @ManpreetDhiman Regarding 3): If you set the field `shortauthor`, the short form of the name should be used when you `\citeauthor{key}`. 
Regarding 4): The type @standard ("National and international standards issued by a standards body such as the International Organization for Standardization") is the correct type for "IS 456:2000". Unfortunately, it is among the unsupported types: "the standard bibliography styles provide no support for these types. When using the standard styles, they will be treated as @misc entries." You could either leave it that way or add @standard to the style.

Comment: I think it should officially be `\mkbibitalic` and `\mkbibbold` instead of `\textit` and `\textbf`

Comment: @ManpreetDhiman You should probably accept this answer.